# How many ways to create object in java?

Tags: java

I know use of "new" keyword and
class.forName()
But I got to know that we can create objects while writing definition of methods.
like methodName(object creation);

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Instead of `Class.forName()` do you mean `Class.newInstance()`?

Comment: No idea what you are talking about. There is only new, and reflection (using either newInstance() or specific constructor objects). But even when you are creating an instance of some anonymous inner class, you start with **new**.

Comment: Ah, you mean like: ```myMethod(new Object());``` ? I don't see how that is different?

Answer (score 5):

these are all the methods through which objects can be created.

**METHOD 1:**

Using new keyword. This is the most common way to create an object in java. Almost 99% of objects are created in this way.

```
 Object object = new Object();
```

**METHOD 2:**

Using Class.forName(). [`Class.forName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-) gives you the class object, which is useful for reflection. The methods that this object has are defined by Java, not by the programmer writing the class. They are the same for every class. Calling newInstance() on that gives you an instance of that class (i.e. callingClass.forName("ExampleClass").newInstance() it is equivalent to calling new ExampleClass()), on which you can call the methods that the class defines, access the visible fields etc.

```
CrunchifyObj object2 = (CrunchifyObj) 
    Class.forName("crunchify.com.example.CrunchifyObj").newInstance();
```

Class.forName() will always use the ClassLoader of the caller, whereas ClassLoader.loadClass() can specify a different ClassLoader. I believe that Class.forName initializes the loaded class as well, whereas the ClassLoader.loadClass() approach doesn’t do that right away (it’s not initialized until it’s used for the first time).

**METHOD 3 :**

Using clone(). The [`Object::clone()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone--) can be used to create a copy of an existing object.

```
CrunchifyObj secondObject = new CrunchifyObj();
CrunchifyObj object3 = (CrunchifyObj) secondObject.clone();
```

**METHOD 4:**

Using [`Class::newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--) method. See [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html).

```
Object object4 = CrunchifyObj.class.getClassLoader().loadClass("crunchify.com.example.CrunchifyObj").newInstance();
```

**METHOD 5:**

Using [Object Deserialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html). Object Deserialization is nothing but creating an object from its [serialized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) form.

```
// create a new file with an ObjectOutputStream
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("crunchify.txt");
ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(out);

// write something in the file
oout.writeObject(object3);
oout.flush();

// create an ObjectInputStream for the file we created before
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("crunchify.txt"));
CrunchifyObj object5 = (CrunchifyObj) ois.readObject();
```

**METHOD 6:**

Use the [`Constructor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html) class from the [java.lang.reflect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html) package, part of [Java Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) facility.

```
Class clazz = CrunchifyObj.class;
Constructor crunchifyCon = clazz.getDeclaredConstructors()[0];
CrunchifyObj obj = (CrunchifyObj) crunchifyCon.newInstance();
```